# Как определять IP в VB.Net?

Tags: ip, vb.net, vbscript, visual-basic

Для периодического определения Ip использую код. Он поставлен на таймер (интервал 3 минуты). Проблема в том , что Окно (MsgBox), вылетает лишь 2-4 раз , а потом зависает программа , без сообщений об ошибках . Заранее благодарю :

```
    Try
        Dim myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://ip-jobs.staff-base.spb.ru/ip.cgi")
        Dim myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim myStreamReader As New StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251))
        IP = myStreamReader.ReadLine.Remove(0, 8)
        IP = IP.Remove(IP.Length - 2, 2)
        MsgBox(IP)
    Catch e As WebException
        MsgBox("!!!-!!!")
    End Try`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка вроде в чём - то типа переполнения переменной, мне кажется, что если вынести объявление переменных в подпрограмму (скорее в функцию), то они не будут "переполняться", хотя я могу заблуждаться.